# How to transfer 2010 tfs database to a new server

Tags: c#, tfs

We have old server with VS2010 TFS server installed and it broke hardware issue, and now we have to move to new server. How to move a database to a new server? We do have a database backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's MSDN's article [Restore Data to a Different Server or Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516.aspx). It has a detailed set of steps on restoring from backups.

These steps also assume that SQL Server has used [Marked Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187014.aspx). Another piece of this is the article [Back Up Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070.aspx).

> To successfully back up Team Foundation Server, you must not only back up all databases that the deployment uses, you must also synchronize the backups to the same point in time. You can manage this synchronization most effectively if you use marked transactions.